# this.myBooks giving error when i call out of ajax function and data return in json formats

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need result in this.myBooks and ajax data return in json format when i call this.mybooks out of this ajax function give error that is undefined.

```
  $.ajax({url: "dtest.html", success: function(result){
    this.MyBooks = result;
  }});
```

Comment: please upload your function

Comment: Please try to add the code which creates problem for you.

Comment: Hello Ali! Thanks for posting your question, but we need more information in order to help you. Can you please provide a code sample of your current attempts?

Comment: `this.MyBooks` is undefined in the current scope.  Did you possibly mean `this.myBooks`?  Can you upload the rest of the relevant code if not?